# Connectivity issue with new hub on one device only

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Recently my landlord changed their internet service to a different package using Sky cos of which they are now using a new Hub. 
When my Desktop connects to this new Hub, the internet connection is terrible. Google UK home page takes minutes to load. Every now and then
in maybe once in a couple of hours, able to play a Youtube video for a min or 2 and connection barely exists again.

Bear in mind the connection had never been great here but not this bad. When I connect this new network to my mobile phone or laptop, everything is 
working fine as before, no issues. The issue is isolated to my Desktop.

Doubt it matters but to note the Desktop having issue is a Windows 10 machine. Laptop is a Mac and Phone is a Samsung.

Whats puzzling is when I ping www.google.com, I am able to get responses. Average time is 21ms.

1. Restarted my Desktop.
2. Restarted the HUB.
3. Network works fine on Mobile phone / laptop, issue only on desktop.
4. Pinged google.com and able to get response at an average time of 21ms. Yet unable to go to Google homepage.
5. Tried using Chrome, Firefox and Edge. all same problems.
6. Using windows 10. Tried using wifi Diagnostic tools. No issues found.
7. Signal shows 2 bars out of 4. Not great (as usual) but there is signal.
8. Desktop uses a wifi adapter which has no issue based on the Diagnostic plus I am getting the signal
9. Tried shifting the desktop / wifi antenna to face in different angle to see if it makes a difference. No difference.
10. Thought maybe need sometime for signal to stabilize after an install but this is now over a week.
11. landlord's device working fine too including the television.
12. Doesn't matter if many devices are using the network or I am the only one using the wifi. Same issue.

In terms of recent changes, only can think of 2.

1. Change of Sky Hub.
2. I installed ZenMate VPN, but it is turned off anyway. Plus it is only on Chrome Browser and issue persists across all browsers.

Please advice what I can do.

Edit:

Laptop DNS : 192.168.0.1 (There were 2 DNS servers, both same ip)

Desktop DNS : 
Default server: unknown
Address: fd13:68b9:a0e2:0:a2bd:cdff:fe8d:aaf0

Comment: @K7AAY Updated the question. Unsure if this is the details you re asking. Let me know if it is something else. Thanks.

Comment: @K7AAY Tried to uncheck ipv6 option under the network settings for the desktop. This made it switch back to ipv4 and match the same dns as the laptop but connection still down on desktop.

Comment: Have yoy tried replacing the etherndt cable between the desktop and hub?

Comment: @davidgo Desktop is connected via wifi not cable.

Comment: Bit of a long shot, but try reducing the MTU of your WIFI interface. (Try1400). If this does not improve things set it back. If it does, let us know so we can tune it.

Comment: @davidgo Reducing MTU didn't make a difference.